# Hiberate adds a column of a primitive type field as NonNullable

Tags: java, hibernate

I am adding a column with Hibernate. Of course hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property is set to "update". Unchanged class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    public Foo() {

    }
}
```

Changed class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private int newValue = 0;

    public Foo() {

    }
}
```

When I am adding a column of a primitive type, like above I get following error:

```
Caused by: ERROR 42601: In an ALTER TABLE statement, the column 'NEWVALUE' has been specified as NOT NULL and either the DEFAULT clause was not specified or was specified as DEFAULT NULL.
```

I am wondering why, because according to @Column API "*if no Column annotation is specified, the default values apply.*" and the default value for nullable attribute is "true".

What is strange - I get no error for String or any other Object. It simply puts "null" in old rows. Also - I do not get error for a primitive type if I exclusively set nullable to true .

```
private String newValue = "0"; //Gives no error

private String newValue; //Gives no error

@Column (nullable = true)
private int newValue; // Gives no error
```

The conclusion is that hibernate sets columns of a primitives as nonnullable on default. When I add a column, there are some legacy rows, which doesn't have value for the new column, which throws an error.

The question is if I can change somewhere this behaviour globally without exclusively setting @Column (nullable = true) every time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just declare newValue as `Integer` instead of `int`? This will make it `nullable=true` by default:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private Integer newValue;

    public Foo() {

    }
}
```

`nullable=true` for primitive types doesn't really make sense, as the can't have `null` values. You cannot write: `int a = null;`